# how to redirect Skype app from swift(iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, skype

I read the pages in stackoverflow and I can understand that I can embed or redirect to Skype app from app I code, but I couldn't find how to make it on iOS even whether it's possible or not.

I want to redirect to skype triggered by pushing button in my iOS app(swift).Please teach me how to do that(If it is not possible, I also want to know that)

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

when you build your app for iOS 9 and above and you need to call URL schemes, you will now need to declare them in your apps Info.plist. There is a new key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`.

[image]

you can do this in helps of `canOpenURL:`

**Objective-C**

```
NSURL *skype = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:"]]; .
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:skype]) {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:skype];
} else {
// skype not Installed in your Device
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]];  // or use https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype-for-iphone/id304878510?mt=8
}
```

**Swift**

```
var skype: NSURL = NSURL(string: String(format: "skype:"))! //add object skype like this
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(skype) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(skype)
 }
else {
// skype not Installed in your Device
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL("http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype")
}
```

for example see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745885.aspx)

Comment: your problem is solved or not bro

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to make it!

Comment: Thanks to you, I did it ! I appreciate you so much!